# ASP.NET MVC 3 controllers throwing exceptions even though I have a catch?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 app, I have the following code:

```
try
{
    return new ProxyResult(new Uri("http://example.org"));
}
catch (WebException)
{
}
```

However, when I try to access the page, I get a WebException (404 Not Found)... but the WebException should be caught. I don't understand how this can possibly jump right out of my catch.

Comment: The 404 is probably being thrown by IIS, before it gets to your code...  Or from some other point, not inside that try block...  Have you tried breakpointing it to see if it's running that line?

Comment: No... like I said I'm getting a WebException. Yellow screen of death. This also happened when returning a FileResult with catch for FileNotFoundException and DirectoryNotFoundException. I changed the code to use File.Exists instead and then it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you are putting in your `try` block is a simple constructor call to the `ProxyResult` which by the way is not some standard result => it's probably something custom. The actual execution of the result (the invoke of the `ExecuteResult`) method which might potentially throw the exception you are expecting happens much later and outside of your controller action. That's the reason why no exception is throw in your controller action. You should put the try/catch inside the ExecuteResult method of this custom `ProxyResult` class that you have written.

Comment: Thing is, ProxyResult is supposed to be reusable. Think about returning a FileResult using Controller.File, how would one handle FileNotFoundExceptions and DirectoryNotFoundExceptions, for example?

Comment: @Jake Petroules, as stated in my answer, exceptions in custom action results should be handled inside the overriden `ExecuteResult` method of this custom action result and act appropriately.

Comment: I found that I can do the following: `var proxy = new ProxyResult(...); proxy.Execute(this.ControllerContext); return proxy;`

I know ActionResults are not 'supposed' to be executed in the controller itself, but will this actually cause any adverse effects?

Answer (score 1):

The proxy result isn't executed until after the action method is returned.  All you are doing is returning an instruction for MVC to process AFTER it has returned.

Use the HandleError attribute to handle exceptions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx